# MS Graph Service Client - How to prove a subscription was created?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code: (which used to work and really should work from what I understand from MS' documentation)

```
    [Route("msgraphsubscription")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<String> msgraphsubscription()
    {
        try{
            this.userId = "<guid>"
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GenerateGraphAuthToken(this.accountManagerParameters);

            var subscription = new Subscription
            {
                ChangeType = "updated",
                NotificationUrl= notificationURL,
                Resource = $"users/{userId}/drive/root",
              
                ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-04-23T18:23:45.9356913Z"),
                ClientState = "secretClientValue",
                LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
            };

            await graphClient.Subscriptions
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(subscription);
         
            return $"New subscriptionID:  {subscription.Id.ToString()}";
        }
        catch(Exception ex){

            Console.Write(ex);
            return ""; 
        }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error on the return statement in the try{} block:

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at msgraphtests.msgraphsubscription() in /src/demos/msgraph/SubscriptionManager.cs:line 132}
error CS1733: Expected expression
```

**What's Broken / Not working**

The code actually creates a subscription. But... it doesn't return the subscription ID.

**What I've Checked**

1. Verified data.  Using Postman, I have created a subscription request using the exact same user, and notification url. I pasted both notification URLs from the POSTMAN request and from my app into a text editor, along with both user ids. Then I do a search and verify that the URL from postman actually matches the one from the vscode file.  So i'm fairly certain it's not a typo in those fields.
2. I put a breakpoint though on the return statement, and checked out the contents of my "subscription" variable and this is what it shows:

   {Microsoft.Graph.Subscription}
   AdditionalData [IDictionary]:null
   ApplicationId [string]:null
   ChangeType [string]:"updated"
   ClientState [string]:"secretClientValue"
   CreatorId [string]:null
   EncryptionCertificate [string]:null
   EncryptionCertificateId [string]:null
   ExpirationDateTime:{2021-04-23 6:23:45 PM +00:00}
   Resource [string]:"users//drive/root"

But in postman, i see this new subscription:

```
{
    "id": "a5234fffd-75f0-3364-bd12-ddddassf",
    "resource": "users/<userguid>/drive/root",
    "applicationId": "asdfasdf-97ec-1b33-8888-asdfasdf",
    "changeType": "updated",
    "clientState": null,
    "notificationUrl": "<mynotificationURL>",
    "notificationQueryOptions": null,
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
    "expirationDateTime": "2021-04-23T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "creatorId": "asdfr-52f5-4822-fffs-afwerwer",
    "includeResourceData": null,
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
    "encryptionCertificate": null,
    "encryptionCertificateId": null
},
```

3. I changed the code to explicitly request the subscription.Id to be returned like this:

   ```
           await graphClient.Subscriptions
               .Request()
               .Select(subscription => new {
                   subscription.Id,
                   subscription.ExpirationDateTime

               })
               .AddAsync(subscription);
           return $"New subscriptionID:  {subscription.ToString()}";
   ```

There are no errors... but the id with a value of Null is still being returned to me.

**Question**

Does anyone know of another way to "prove" the subscription was created using the subscription object itself? (what artifacts can i check in the subscription object?) Did something change on the MS end? cuz this used to work just fine.

THanks.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code, it seems that you're expecting that Microsoft's code updates the Subscription object you pass into .AddAsync() method.

However, looking at Microsoft's implementation of the method, they are returning a whole new object back. So, you should do the following:

```
Subscription subscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(subscription);
```

Comment: @dot Can you please let me know if my answer helped you?